# Deep find object in array and edit then put back in place

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, filter

```
const data = [{name: "item1", key: 1}, {name: "item2", key: 2, children: [{name: "item3", key: 3}]}]
```

**each item can have children and objects in a children)**

when will click to edit the function should give finded object by key or by given object:

> findObj(3) //find by key
>
> //result {name: "item3", key: 3}

when will click to save after the editing the edited object should be saved in own place:

> saveEditing({name: "editedName", key: 3})
>
> //result [{name: "item1", key: 1}, {name: "item2", key: 2, children: [{name: "editedName", key: 3}]}]

Comment: What did you already tried?

Comment: klediooo not yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Find item by key**

```js
function findItemByKey(data, key){
  for(let node of data){
    if(node.key === key){
      return node;
    }
    if(node.children){
      let result = findItemByKey(node.children, key)
      if(result) {
        return result;
      }
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}

let result = findItemByKey(data, 3);
console.log(result); // { name: "item3", key: 3 }
```

**Save item by key**

```js
function saveItemByKey(data, key, name){
  let result = findItemByKey(data, key);
  if(result){
    result.name = name;
  }
}
```

Just some rough solutions. You should be able to customize it from there.

Answer (score 1):

```js
/**
 * @param {Number} key 
 * @param {Array} array 
 * @returns {Object}
 */
function findObj(key, array) {
  for (const item of array) {
    if (item.key === key) {
      return item
    } 
    else if (item.children) {
      const foundChildren = findObj(key, item.children)
      if (foundChildren) return foundChildren
    }
  }
  return null
}

/**
 * @param {Object} obj 
 * @param {Array} array 
 * @returns Boolean
 */
function saveEditing(obj, array) {
  const foundObj = obj.key && findObj(obj.key, array)
  if (foundObj) {
    Object.assign(foundObj, {...obj})
    return true
  }
  return false
}
```